# How to install cryptography library on Docker container?

Tags: python, docker, odoo, odoo-14

I develop our company website with Odoo 14. I installed Odoo on my local machine (`macOS Monterey (12.5.1)`) via Docker. I use Docker Desktop and I have created `docker-compose.yaml` taking [official Odoo docker image page](https://hub.docker.com/_/odoo) as reference.

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: odoo:14.0
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8069:8069"
    volumes:
      - odoo-web-data:/var/lib/odoo©
      - ./config:/etc/odoo
      - ./addons:/mnt/extra-addons
  db:
    image: postgres:10
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo
      - POSTGRES_USER=odoo
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    volumes:
      - odoo-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
      - ./db:/db
volumes:
  odoo-web-data:
  odoo-db-data:
```

I wanted to install Odoo eCommerce module but I couldn't. It gives that error:

> Unable to install module "account_edi_proxy_client" because an
> external dependency is not met: Python library not installed:
> cryptography

I already installed it but it still gives the same error.

```
$ pip3 install cryptography
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (38.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.12 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from cryptography) (1.15.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from cffi>=1.12->cryptography) (2.21)
```

There were some suggestion to install `pycryptodome` instead, I installed it as well but still the same result.

After all, I realised that I was trying installing cryptography library on my local machine and actually I had to install it in the docker container.

So, I ran this command:

```
docker exec -it [container_name] pip3 install cryptography
```

and I got this error now:

> Command "/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-ynyd_o0_ --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools>=40.6.0,!=60.9.0 wheel "cffi>=1.12; platform_python_implementation != 'PyPy'" setuptools-rust>=0.11.4" failed with error code 1 in None

What is missing here, any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to upgrade pip and setuptools first and then install cryptography

```
docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID pip3 install --upgrade pip
docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID pip3 install --upgrade setuptools

docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID pip3 install cryptography
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Waleed. I installed cryptography in this way. Meanwhile, I found another way with creating Dockerfile and declare there to what to install. I'm going to post that solution as well as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to @Waleed's solution, there is another way to install cryptography (or another) library into docker container. The difference here is creating a `Dockerfile` and configure the `docker-compose.yaml`.

**docker-compose.yaml:**

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8069:8069"
    volumes:
      - odoo-web-data:/var/lib/odoo©
      - ./config:/etc/odoo
      - ./addons:/mnt/extra-addons
  db:
    image: postgres:10
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo
      - POSTGRES_USER=odoo
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    volumes:
      - odoo-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
      - ./db:/db
volumes:
  odoo-web-data:
  odoo-db-data:
```

I copied the Dockerfile (v14) from [the official Odoo github page](https://github.com/odoo/docker/blob/master/14.0/Dockerfile) and additionally, I declared to install cryptography library (`python3-cryptography`).

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM debian:buster-slim
LABEL Odoo S.A. <info@odoo.com>

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-xo", "pipefail", "-c"]

# Generate locale C.UTF-8 for postgres and general locale data
ENV LANG C.UTF-8

# Install some deps, lessc and less-plugin-clean-css, and wkhtmltopdf
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        ca-certificates \
        curl \
        dirmngr \
        fonts-noto-cjk \
        gnupg \
        libssl-dev \
        node-less \
        npm \
        python3-num2words \
        python3-pdfminer \
        python3-pip \
        python3-phonenumbers \
        python3-pyldap \
        python3-qrcode \
        python3-renderpm \
        python3-setuptools \
        python3-slugify \
        python3-vobject \
        python3-watchdog \
        python3-xlrd \
        python3-xlwt \
        python3-cryptography \
        xz-utils \
    && curl -o wkhtmltox.deb -sSL https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.5/wkhtmltox_0.12.5-1.buster_amd64.deb \
    && echo 'ea8277df4297afc507c61122f3c349af142f31e5 wkhtmltox.deb' | sha1sum -c - \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends ./wkhtmltox.deb \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* wkhtmltox.deb

# install latest postgresql-client
RUN echo 'deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ buster-pgdg main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list \
    && GNUPGHOME="$(mktemp -d)" \
    && export GNUPGHOME \
    && repokey='B97B0AFCAA1A47F044F244A07FCC7D46ACCC4CF8' \
    && gpg --batch --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys "${repokey}" \
    && gpg --batch --armor --export "${repokey}" > /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/pgdg.gpg.asc \
    && gpgconf --kill all \
    && rm -rf "$GNUPGHOME" \
    && apt-get update  \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y postgresql-client \
    && rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install rtlcss (on Debian buster)
RUN npm install -g rtlcss

# Install Odoo
ENV ODOO_VERSION 14.0
ARG ODOO_RELEASE=20221226
ARG ODOO_SHA=ec385462138e5027be4cf452844a3df3a8ef3573
RUN curl -o odoo.deb -sSL http://nightly.odoo.com/${ODOO_VERSION}/nightly/deb/odoo_${ODOO_VERSION}.${ODOO_RELEASE}_all.deb \
    && echo "${ODOO_SHA} odoo.deb" | sha1sum -c - \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends ./odoo.deb \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* odoo.deb

# Copy entrypoint script and Odoo configuration file
# COPY ./entrypoint.sh /
COPY ./config/odoo.conf /etc/odoo/

# Set permissions and Mount /var/lib/odoo to allow restoring filestore and /mnt/extra-addons for users addons
RUN chown odoo /etc/odoo/odoo.conf \
    && mkdir -p /mnt/extra-addons \
    && chown -R odoo /mnt/extra-addons
VOLUME ["/var/lib/odoo", "/mnt/extra-addons"]

# Expose Odoo services
EXPOSE 8069 8071 8072

# Set the default config file
ENV ODOO_RC /etc/odoo/odoo.conf

# COPY wait-for-psql.py /usr/local/bin/wait-for-psql.py

# Set default user when running the container
USER odoo

# ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["odoo"]
```